# realm: Specify one realm to join

Tags: linux

Hello I am trying to join Amazon linux server to AD & used below command:

```
source /etc/os-release

realm join -U <username>@<EXAMPLE.COM> <hostname> --computer-ou="OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx" --os-name=$PRETTY_NAME  --os-version=$VERSION_ID -v
```

But i am getting an error as below:
O/p

```
realm: Specify one realm to join
```

And when i use below command it gets success.

```
realm join -U <username>@<EXAMPLE.COM> <hostname> -v
```

Can some one help me with first command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a double quotes to your variables :

```
realm join -U <username>@<EXAMPLE.COM> <hostname> --computer-ou="OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx" --os-name="$PRETTY_NAME"  --os-version="$VERSION_ID" -v
```